# How to make a parameterized query in a method that made for SQL insertions?

Tags: c#, sql, parameterized

I really don't know how to explain it well in the title, but here's my problem.

Among many overloading methods i have made this method that's its only purpose is to insert given values into a give table :

```
public static int Insert(string cs, string table, string[] values)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            string strCommand = string.Format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1})", 
                table, 
                values.Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " +b)));
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(strCommand, con);
            con.Open();
            int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return result;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it's not using parameterized queries, isn't it?

I really want to implement this concept into it but i have no idea how.

Comment: Currently all your values are string? What if some values are numbers?

Comment: You're not far off.  In this case though, you'd probably need to make two passes in a loop to get what you want.  Once to create parameters in the query text, and another time to add the parameters to the command object.  As long as you have them sorted in the order you want in `values` it will probably work.  You could theoretically do them in the same loop if you wanted, and use a `StringBuilder` to append the formats as you build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dictionary containing column names and their respective values

```
   Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string,object>();
   values.Add("userid", 1022);
        values.Add("username", "JFord");
        values.Add("IsActive", 0);
   string table = "users";
```

usage:

```
MyClass.Insert("connection", "users", values);
```

Method

```
public static int Insert(string cs, string table, Dictionary<string,object> values)
{
        string strCommand = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1})",
            table, "@"+String.Join(", @", values.Keys));

 //strCommand becomes: "INSERT INTO users VALUES (@userid, @username, @IsActive)"

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(strCommand, conn);

        foreach (string key in values.Keys)
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + key, values[key]);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your method to pass a string array with parameter names and an equal length array of objects containing the parameter values

```
public static int Insert(string cs, string table, string[] paramNames, object[] paramValues)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            string strCommand = string.Format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} VALUES ({1})", table, 
                paramNames.Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " +b)));

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(strCommand, con);
            for(int x = 0; x < paramNames.Length; x++)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[x], paramValues[x]);

            con.Open();
            int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return result;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

you could call this procedure using something like this

```
string[] parNames = new string[] {"@keyID", "@custName"};
object[] parValues = new object[] {1, "Mike"};
DBHelper.Insert("constring", "customers", parNames, parValues);
```

Let me say, however, that this approach as many drawbacks. Because you don't pass a specific set of columns you are forced to pass the value for every column and this will give you problems if your table contains an Identity column. (You can't explicity set a value for an Identity columns.)

Thus, is far better, to pass an array of column names instead of an array of parameter names.
With this array you could customize better your query (omitting fields for example) and the parameter names could be derived by the column names.

```
public static int Insert(string cs, string table, string[] colNames, object[] paramValues)
{
    ......
          string strCommand = string.Format(
                "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", table, 
                colNames.Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " +b)),
                colNames.Select(n => "@" + n).Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " + b)));
    .....

            for(int x = 0; x < colNamesNames.Length; x++)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + colNames[x], paramValues[x]);

}
```

and of course change your parameter in the call to use column names instead of parameter names.

```
string[] colNames = new string[] {"ID", "Name"};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using positional values in the insert statement you will run into problems if table columns are added, removed or reordered. It is a better idea to use a named insert

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (x, y, z)
```

Therefore you would have to pass the column names as well. This also allows you to skip non required columns or identity columns and timestamps, calculated columns or columns filled by a trigger.

```
public static int Insert(string cs, string table, string[] columns, object[] values)
```

I also changed the type of the values array to `object[]` since this allows you to pass the values in their correct type (e.g. an integer value as `int` or a date/time value as `DateTime`.
Also we don't add the values directly to the sql statement, instead we use parameter placeholders (`@xy`). Here we simply use the column names prefixed with "@".

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (@col1, @col2, @col3)
```

```cs
string cmd = string.Format(
    "INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", 
    table,
    columns.Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " + b))
    columns.Select(c => "@" + c).Aggregate((a, b) => (a + ", " + b)));
```

Now we have to add the values as parameters to the `SqlCommand`

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++) {
    com.AddWithValue("@" + columns[i], values[i]);
}
```

The other parts (opening the connection, creating and executing the command etc.) remain the same.

---

Example:

```
int result = Insert(
    cs, "mytable", 
    new string[] { "id", "name", "birthdate" },
    new object[] { 107, "John", new DateTime(1980,7,19) }
);
```